# How to sort all the records in a file in python from the 7th column?

Tags: python, file

So I have a file:

```
202010000  Asem       ICS104      0         100         100         200
202010000  Asem       ICS108      2          75          -1          75
202010001  Khalid     ICS202      0          -1          -1          -1
201928690  Hamza      ICS104      0          80          -1          80
201928440  Abdullah   ICS104      0         100         100         200
202012340  Hassan     ICS104      3          60          38          98
201872630  Hadi       ICS108      8          90          90         180
201562730  Anwar      ICS202      4          75          75         150
201829380  Ali        ICS210      3          90          75         165
```

I need to display all the records in this file in descending order of the total grades (7th column). I asked a very similar question to sort the records alphabetically according to the names (2nd column). The answer for that was this:

```
studentFile = open(input("Enter file name: "), "r")
lines = studentFile.readlines()
    for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda l: l.split()[1]):
        print(line)
```

I tried to do something very similar for the 7th column like this:

```
studentFile = open(input("Enter file name: "), "r")
lines = studentFile.readlines()
    for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda l: l.split()[6], reverse= True):
        print(line)
```

But it doesn't give me the numbers in the correct descending order:

```
202012340  Hassan     ICS104      3          60          38          98

201928690  Hamza      ICS104      0          80          -1          80

202010000  Asem       ICS108      2          75          -1          75

202010000  Asem       ICS104      0         100         100         200

201928440  Abdullah   ICS104      0         100         100         200

201872630  Hadi       ICS108      8          90          90         180

201829380  Ali        ICS210      3          90          75         165

201562730  Anwar      ICS202      4          75          75         150

202010001  Khalid     ICS202      0          -1          -1          -1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a `.csv` file or some other type of a file?

Comment: @baduker its a ```.txt``` file

Comment: I noticed its starts in descending with the 2 digit numbers i.e 98, 80, 75. Then it starts the 3 digit numbers and starts descending, if that helps. Maybe it has something to do with the space before the 2 digit numbers?

Comment: "split" gives you strings, so you're comparing the string values of column 7 and not their int versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert it to `int` before sorting, try this:

```
studentFile = open(input("Enter file name: "), "r")
lines = studentFile.readlines()
    for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda l: int(l.split()[6]), reverse= True):
        print(line)
```

output:

```
202010000  Asem       ICS104      0         100         100         200

201928440  Abdullah   ICS104      0         100         100         200

201872630  Hadi       ICS108      8          90          90         180

201829380  Ali        ICS210      3          90          75         165

201562730  Anwar      ICS202      4          75          75         150

202012340  Hassan     ICS104      3          60          38          98

201928690  Hamza      ICS104      0          80          -1          80

202010000  Asem       ICS108      2          75          -1          75

202010001  Khalid     ICS202      0          -1          -1          -1
```

edit: @cwittah already said this in the comments, I didn't see it as I was typing out the answer